# Shortcuts for snippets in Adobe Dreamweaver CS5

Tags: adobe, text-editor, dreamweaver, flash-cs5

I found a few related questions but I'm concerned I won't be able to find an answer after viewing the other results.

Does Dreamweaver CS5 have snippet shortcuts that allow the user to first type something and then hit that command to enter the text? I'm not sure how to explain it or what big words to use, so I guess I'll use examples from other editors.

Notepad++ lets to you create a snippet and then name is "example1". Then in your code if you type "example1" followed by CTRL+ENTER it will insert the code in the snippet. CTRL+ENTER is the only real key binding.

Komodo edit does the same thing, except with "example1" followed by CTRL+T

Dreamweave does snippets, and you can add shortcuts to them, but you waste a key bind on every snippet you want to add. That's hardly efficient. I'd run out of keybinds and overwrite a lot of important ones!

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is No

Howerver, there is an extension that inserts HTML content based on text based on CSS called [Zen Coding](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/) (look under the downloads listed on the left). This extension allows you to type in CSS then hit a keyboard combo and that inserts the appropriate code onto your page. I don't know how easy it would be to allow the extension to work with arbitrary code chunks associated with user specified keywords.

FWIW: I've seen this referred to as Code Templates. Eclipse supports code templates, see the [Using code templates](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-EditorTemplates.htm) section of the Eclipse help system.